# Loop diagonally on top half of a square matrix in Java?

Tags: java, for-loop, matrix, multidimensional-array, diagonal

Not sure how to structure the loop to iterate the matrix in this order. The red is the middle diagonally which should be ignored. The yellow is the cells I need to process but in the order of the arrows from bottom to top (bigger arrow to smaller arrow). Is it possible? If anyone can provide iteration logic I would highly appreciate it!

[image]

Comment: Do you have an idea?

Comment: @akuzminykh I've tried with a nested for-loop but struggling how to index i and j and the logic to update them since the outer loop jumps around rows for each iteration of the inner loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the following is the iteration structure that you need

```
for(int i = 1; i < matrix.size; ++i)
    for(int j = 0; j < matrix.size; ++j)
        matrix[j][i+j] //do your stuff
```

Comment: The inner loop should have the following condition to be precise:
`j < matrix.size - i`

Comment: isn't `i = 1, j = 3` possible with this solution? If so, is that what the OP wants?